# Delphi ListView OnSelectItem fires twice

Tags: delphi

ListView's OnSelectItem event fires twice. ListView is virtual in VsReport mode. How to prevent this behavior or is there a better workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The event is firing for selection and unselection. If node X was selected and you select node Y it will report:

1. node X  selected=false
2. node Y  selected=true

You can make the behavior visible by :

> ```
> procedure TForm5.ListView1SelectItem(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem;
>   Selected: Boolean);
> begin
>   Showmessage(Item.Caption +' - '+IntToStr(Integer(Selected)));
> end;
> ```

If you want to react only on selection just  evaluate `Selected`.

Comment: I know 'für' is German for 'for', but I don't know what 'nodex' and 'nodey' means.